# Sublime text 2 completions

Tags: sublimetext2

Making the *.sublime-completions file, I found the "bug" which occurs when typing a long function like:

```
one.two.three.four.five(One := One_var, Two := Two_Var);
```

So if you type the whole function:

"one.two.three.four.five" and then press tab - it will paste another part of functions without issues.

But, if you type "one.two.thr" - and then in pop-up hint see that function and hit "Enter" it will replaces like:

[image: wrong autocomplete]

```
one.two.one.two.three.four.five(One := One_var, Two := Two_Var);
```

How can I configure trigger to replace "one.two.thr" to correct function format?

[image: useless words]

This is my trigger.

```
        { "trigger": "one.two.three.four.five", "contents": "${TM_CURRENT_LINE/(.*)/(one.two.three.four.five)/}(One := One_var, Two := Two_Var);" },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, but a default setting of Sublime Text. By default, dots are treated as `word_separators`. Hence every time you type `.`, the completion trigger will be reset.

**Example:**

Let's assume we have only the following completions available:

```
{
  "trigger": "one.two.three",
  "contents": "one.two.three.four.five"
},
{
  "trigger": "two",
  "contents": "it_takes_two"
}
```

Now, let's type them in Sublime Text (the `|` marks the cursor position!)

```
one|     -> will trigger "one.two.three.four.five"
one.|    -> new word, forgot about "one.two.three.four.five"
one.two| -> will trigger "it_takes_two"
```

In the last case, both completions will be listed in the completion popup does to the fuzzy match for ”two”. However, the closer match ”two” will have a higher priority.

To fix this, you can edit the `word_separators` setting in a package setting or your global user settings. By default the setting treats the following characters as word separators:

```
 ./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?
```

Alternatively, you ommit the dots from your completion triggers, e.g. use `one-two-three` instead of `one.two.three`.

Comment: Yes, now I understand. But looks like the way - to remove dots from "word_separators" is not the best way. It can break the usual behaviour.

I now found another way, but this is not a fix, just another approach to format autocomplete file.